# How to link custom field to shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I'm trying to link a custom field to a custom shortcode so the shortcode shows displays only the posts with the custom field selected to it.

This is my code below for my shortcode as you can see the key is my custom felid "flash_deal". When I enter the shortcode I just get all the perk psots and no the custom field perk posts?

```
add_shortcode('foundry_flash', 'shortcode_query_flash');
function shortcode_query_flash($atts, $content){
extract(shortcode_atts(array( // a few default values
   'post_type' => 'perks',
      'posts_per_page' => -1 ,
          'meta_query' => array(
          array(
              'key' => 'flash_deal', // name of custom field
              'value' => '"yes"', // matches exactly "red"
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
              )
          )
), $atts));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is simply setting up variables - not running any queries at all (see [extract documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) & [shortcode_atts documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts)).

I assume you have more code you just didn't add here, so likely the problem is the double quotes around `yes` that are causing issues. It's literally looking for "*quote*yes*quote*".

As a general working example to get "Parks" Post based on custom meta, [you need to use WP_Query as in the docs here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'parks',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'flash_deal',
            'value'   => 'yes',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then use a [Nested Loop setup to loop through the results](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Nested_Loops).